# Jquery mobile security for new project

Tags: security, jquery-mobile

We are currently looking at the possibility of a jquery mobile app for company employees.  But, we don't have a ton of experience and would like suggestions on how to do security?

Background:

- Salesmen with Android phones or Iphones
- most of the time on foreign wireless or 3g/4g, sometimes on intranet/internal wireless.
- Would like app to show customer info, current orders, pricing, etc
- Windows 2008 Active Directory environment.

Obviously because of the sensitive customer data, security would be fairly important.

Just barely researching jquery mobile, and wondering what the ideas for security are out there?

Also, all the phones are company provided, and we have access to the full phone, would using something hardware/os related on the phone provide extra security?  A hash of the imei, phone number, mac address, etc?

Thanks

Comment: What's the backend? PHP .NET, etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the company portal on HTTPS - assuming you are just building a regular site. If you are planning on wrapping it in a e.g. a PhoneGap layer, be sure to communicate securely.

Comment: Some claims that it is possible: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dose-jquery-mobile-support-https

Answer (score 0):

Make the backend API stateless (no sessions) and provide the full authentication credentials in the AJAX headers. You'll want to transmit username, password, and device ID over SSL on each call that way you can authenticate the device in addition to the user.

You can manage the equivalent of a session timeout on the app itself using setInterval() in javascript. When the timeout expires just clear the user credentials in javascript and have the app go back to the signin screen. You can also add a check on the beforepagechange event in JQM to see if the user is authenticated and, if not, redirect them back to your signin screen.